# Remove time from my string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I am creating a web app in asp.net in which I am fetching the time from my database through string and printing the string date format in my database is `2016-10-15 00:00:00.000` and when I print the string the date format is showing like `10-Oct-16 12:00:00 AM` but I just want to print `10-Oct-16` I tried

```
string reformattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdate, "dd-MM-yyyy", null)
                                 .ToString("MMM d, yyyy");
```

This but it is me showing:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Can anyone suggest me a better way?

Comment: Why are you fetching your date as a string? What's wrong with using the actual correct data type?

Comment: what type is `txtdate`?

Comment: in my table date is coming as string

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh That's daft. If it's a `datetime`, store and retrieve it as a `datetime`.

Comment: So change your table? It's a bad idea to store dates in a DB in a string. This will ultimately cause you no end of trouble

Comment: As the name suggests ParseExact expects an exact match - so either change the format to be an exact match or use the more generic Parse method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff`, the format you have inputted is only `dd-MM-yyyy`.

This is causing the error. Change this to:

```
string reformattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-10-15 00:00:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                 .ToShortDateString();
```

EDIT: You can also use `ToString("dd-MMM-yy")` instead of `ToShortDateString()` to get the desired output.

e.g.:

```
string reformattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-10-15 00:00:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                 .ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
```